In IDEA it show me an error in a line that doesn't exists in the file
In an Angular project I have a file with 46 lines and the compiler shows me that there is an error in a line that doesn't exist in the file because it has only 46 lines. How is it possible?



The code shown in the error is not the same as the source code. It seems to have introduced , : . between the console and login. Could it be that the source code is somehow transformed during the compilation? Also is it supposed to be console.log instead of console.login?
